# Converting 2D Polygons to 3D in QGIS/PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

I have a buildings layer in QGIS that is stored in Postgis. The layer is MultiPolygon type although I am pretty sure there is only 1 geometry (Polygon) per element.

[image]

I was able to create a height field (height of the building) for each polygon using a LIDAR layer.

Now, I would like to modify the geometry of the layer and convert each building from 2D to 3D using this height field.

In QGIS, I tried the "Set Z Value" Processing algorithm, but when I check the $Z value for each element, I get null. If I open the 3D view, I see it is totally flat.

I also tried "Drape (set Z value from raster)" using a raster created with the heights, and I got the same result.

So my next step was to do it with PostGIS. I created the following query that first converts each point to a point3D, then creates Polylines3D, and finally, Polygonizes the lines:

```
CREATE TABLE "borrarEdif3DPrueba" AS
    WITH points2d AS
        (SELECT id,(ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom AS geom, altura_edificio_max
         FROM "borraEdifConAltura"
        )
    ,
    points3d AS
        (SELECT id, ST_MakePoint(
             st_x(geom),
             st_y(geom),
             altura_edificio_max) AS "geomPoint3D"
             from points2d)
    ,
    edif_line as (SELECT  id, ST_MakeLine("geomPoint3D") AS geom
    FROM points3d
    GROUP BY id)
    ,
    edifpol as (select id, ST_Force3D(ST_setSRID(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Polygonize(geom),3),25830))::geometry(MultiPolygonZ, 25830) as geom from edif_line group by id)
    
    SELECT id, geom from edifpol
```

I imported the layer into QGIS and got the same result: $Z values are null, and in 3D everything is flat.

Comment: are your geometry columns MULTIPOLYGONZ, MULTIPOLYGONMZ or just MULTIPOLYGON?

Comment: Yes, the table is MultiPolygonZ. I add the geometry(MultiPolygonZ, 25830) conversion explicitly in the query just in case

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for visualization, you can use the attribute value directly to show the polygons in 3D, using Layer Styling > `3D View` settings. For extrusion, use data driven override and select the elevation attribute. Then the polygons will appear in 3D.

[image]