Creating a 2.5D effect by filling the gap between two polygons
I have two polygon layers. One is my base/floor. The other is my roof. I have used a geometry generator so that the roof is translated, via expression, at 70 degrees and by a distance of "heightreal."
What I want to do is create a third polygon layer that "fills in the gap" between the original base/floor and the translated one. In other words, create a polygon that is the union of height-1, height-2, height-3, all the way to 0.
That way this new polygon layer simulates the walls of a building. The resulting new polygon will fill in some of the areas that I colored in the screenshot.
Any ideas how to achieve this in geometry generator? 

Do you actually want to create a single 2.5D extruded poly rather than trying to make sides and a roof? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/447911/2856 https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/3d_symbols.html#polygon-layers

I'd go with the 3D-style-option above. Other than that you could extract vertices for the polygons, hope, that vertices representing the top and bottom of the buildiung have the same ID, join their coordinates, create a line from those, and then... idk, there it gets complicated or manual.

I would like to not use the 2.5 or 3D Styler in QGIS. I would like to create a brand new polygon.
I also like Erik's idea but I could never get anything to work by working with vertices.

If you want it to make sure there's no approximation, I think Erik's suggestion is the way to go. One approximation could be to use convex_hull of the top &bottoom polygons
